# Google Tag Manager custom event not set

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

**Setup:**

I have a tag in Google Tag Manager (GTM) that is configured to fire onload:

[image: GTM I]
[image: GTM II]
[image: GTM III]

*My website has the following snippets:*

In the `<head>` section:

```html
<script>
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
      i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
      a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
      })
    (window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'auto');

    //If _gaManaged is true, the page should manage Google Analytics manually.
    if ((typeof _gaManaged) == "undefined" || !_gaManaged) {
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
</script>
```

In the `<body>` section:

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GTM-XXXX"></script>
<noscript>
   <iframe src='//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX' height='0' width='0' style='display:none;visibility:hidden'>                            
   </iframe>                        
</noscript>
<script>
  (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
      'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
      event: 'gtm.js'
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j = d.createElement(s),
      dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
    j.async = true;
    j.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXX');

  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments)
  };
  gtag('js', new Date());
  window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = 'ga';
  window['ga'] = window['ga'] || function() {
    (window['ga'].q = window['ga'].q || []).push(arguments)
  };
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**Issue:**

From one day to the other (on the 21th June) I started getting way too many hits registered as "(not set)". 
i.e. yesterday (start-date -> end-date=yesterday) the total events registered was 142,452 and (not set) ones was 135,891!

**Doubts:**

1. My interpretation of "(not set)" is that the Javascript function returned null, is this a correct assumption?
2. I can understand that some browsers do not support the navigation timing API and that many users have content filters/ad-blockers installed that many don't allow TM data to be collected, however I was not expecting the (not set) value to be so high.

Why, without any changes to tag manager configuration, I started getting so many hits marked as (not set).

3. Is there any change to the javascript function that can be done to correct this?
4. The number of events that GTM seems to account for in any given day is also very low when I compare the number of pageviews on the site.
   I expect it to be lower but not something like 10% of the total pageviews.
   What can explain this? Is there some kind of limit on GTM?
5. Unrelated question: I have a blocking trigger that does not seem to filter out all the negative values returned by the JS function on the tag.

The setup, in the triggers section of Tag manager, that I have is:

Name: Blocking - Page Load Time less than 0
EventType: Custom Event
Filter: Page Load Time less than 0
Tags: 0

Inside the trigger, I have:
Event Name: .
Use regex matching: Checked

What could be wrong?

Comment: Having both gtag.js and GTM seems a bit overkill (gtag basically is a tag manager for Google products only). They use the same infrastructure and the same datalayer, but since you have already configured Analytics via GTM including gtag.js as well seems unnecessary and makes this harder to debug,

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks for the comment.

We need both Google Analytics to track things like number of pageviews, tracking of user behavior, etc and then we need Google Tag Manager for marketing purposes and also the specific case of tracking the page load time as show above.

1. Can I assume then, that I will need both the GA and GTM snippets in each page?

2. If so, is the problem that we are not using the correct/up-to-date snippets for both GA and GTM? It seems also that we don't have it in the correct location within the HTML tags.

Comment: @EikePierstorff ...I suspect that the snippets we are using are old implementations of GA and GTM snippets.